Collab Runtime Gets Disconnect Issue
I am using Google Collab to run my model training, since training set is big I have to run it over a longer period, as I  step away for more than 15 minutes the runtime instance disconnects and I have to start all over again.
Is there any workaround to schedule the model training and run it for longer period without having the need to connect it regularly?
